# Make Hubot send a direct message in HipChat

Tags: javascript, hubot, hipchat

How do I tell Hubot to send a direct message using the HipChat adapter? I've tried many different options without success.

```
module.exports = function (robot) {
  robot.respond(/hi/i, function (msg) {
    msg.send(msg.message.user.room, 'hi'); // outputs to current room
    msg.send(msg.message.user.id, 'hi'); // outputs to current room
    msg.send(msg.message.user, 'hi'); // outputs to current room
    msg.reply('hi'); // @mentions the user in the current room
    msg.reply_to('hi') // no reply_to method though I thought I saw this somewhere
  });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me awhile to find it, but it turns out this works:

```
module.exports = function (robot) {
  robot.respond(/hi/i, function (msg) {
    robot.send({
      user: msg.message.user.jid
    }, 'hi');
  });
};
```